# Using EVENTS API in moodle

Tags: magento, moodle

I am new to moodle, I have a requirement where I am trying to use the Events API. I want to call some magento script on the event of a course being created in moodle. So every time a course is created the custom script will be called. As referred from API course_created event is called when a course is created and we have to write some observer to handle the event. But the example is not so clear to me. Can anyone direct me to work with events API with some example.

Any Help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

First create local plugin in /local/yourpluginname - have a look at /local/readme.txt for a sample structure and refer to http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Local_plugins

Then create /local/yourpluginname/db/events.php to handle the course_created event, something like:

```
$handlers = array (
    'course_created' => array (
        'handlerfile'      => '/local/yourpluginname/lib.php',
        'handlerfunction'  => 'local_yourpluginname_course_created',
        'schedule'         => 'instant',
        'internal'         => 1,
    ),
);
```

Refer to http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Events_API#Handling_an_event

Then create the corresponding function in /local/yourpluginname/lib.php eg:

```
function local_yourpluginname_course_created($course) {
    // Do what you need to do with the course.
}
```

The $course object will be a copy of the record created in mdl_course, so you will have $course->id, $course->shortname etc.

Comment: i tried this..the function local_yourpluginname_course_created is not getting called..can u help

Comment: It looks like I had misspelled 'courese_created' instead of 'course_created'